# Using Vscode launch.json and task.json how can I use the return value of script running in task.json inside launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

For debugging with GDB server on host target I need to retrieved the IP address to pass to the "miDebuggerServerAddress" command. Since the Ip will not always be the same, I have a bash script running as a preLaunchTask that return me the IP address of the target. Is there a way to remember this value or to pass it to the launch.json file afterward?
here a snippet of my launch.json file

> ```
>     {
>         "name": "GDB test",
>         "type": "cppdbg",
>         "request": "launch",
>         "preLaunchTask": "TaskGetIP",
>         "program": "${input:promptPathDgbAppl}",
>         "stopAtEntry": false,
>         "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
>         "miDebuggerServerAddress" : "${return_of_GetIP}:41882",
>         
>         "environment": [],
>         "externalConsole": false,
>         "MIMode": "gdb",
>         "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
>         "setupCommands": [
>             {
>                 "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
>                 "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
>                 "ignoreFailures": true
>             },
>             {
>                 "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
>                 "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
>                 "ignoreFailures": true
>             }
>         ],
>
>     },
> ```

here my task.json

> ```
>      {
>       "label": "TaskGetIP",
>       "type": "shell",
>       "command": "GetIP.sh" 
>
>      },
> ```

So I would like the return of GetIP.sh to be store or use on the "miDebuggerServerAddress" command. Is there a way to do this?
thank you

Comment: if you save the IP in a file you can use the extension I made: [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable), use command [`extension.commandvariable.file.content`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content)

Comment: @rioV8 I tried that actually. Maybe I miss something but from my understanding the content of the file loaded with extension.commandvariable.file.content is done at init and not during run time. So the variable is not refresh with a new IP from the script.

Comment: @rioV8 Am I right with my last comment? Is that suppose to be like that? Maybe I store the value the wrong way. Is there a particular way to store the value in the file. I was using something like this "command": "GetIP.sh > myIP.txt" .

Comment: it all depends when VSC resolves variables, does it wait for the `preLaunchTask` before resolving the launch variables, you can test by putting a dummy IP in `myIP.txt` and see what is used in the command, the dummy or the correct one, can you save the IP inside the `GetIP.sh` script, use the file to use as argument, VSC is not dealing correct with file redirections in task commands, I might spends some time implementing the `task result` open issue

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for your reply. Your are probably right, that VSC resolves variables before preLaunchTask is finished. When I input the proper IP manually in myIP.txt (before launching the debugging session), the Proper IP address is fetch using extension.commandvariable.file.content and the debugging session start as intended. I can also see that myIP.txt is updated with the redirection in "command": "GetIP.sh > myIP.txt". So everything is pointing to the fact that VSC resolve the variable beforehand. I can try to save the ip inside the GetIP.sh to see if the result is the same.

Comment: @rioV8 I tried to save the IP address inside the GetIP.sh. This result in the same behavior where the "miDebuggerServerAddress" have the previous IP address. So everything is pointing to the fact that VSC resolves variable before PreLaunchTask is finished. I wonder if there is a work around?

Comment: if that is the case then implementing `task result` to get info in a launch config will always fail, maybe we should create an issue and ask for `wait for preLaunchTask to end` before resolving launch variables

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for your reply. I am wondering if its the case why the extension.commandvariable.promptStringRemember is working properly?

Comment: do you mean that you use `promptStringRemember` in a `preLaunchTask` and then in the launch config you use a `extension.commandvariable.remember` command to get the string and this works

Comment: @rioV8 no you are right, the use of promptStringRemember is always done in preLaunchTask, or done first in launch and then use in preLaunchTask and not the other way around.